# Is there a version of /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ that runs DB scripts every time the container starts?

Tags: docker

I know that scripts placed under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` will run on the very first container start, but is there an automatic version of this that will run on every container start?

Basically as I'm developing I will often touch/add database init scripts, I'm happy to fill these with `IF NOT EXISTS` clauses to make them idempotent but I need them to run on every container up, and not have to nuke the db volume each time.

Or is this a sign I'm going about development with a dockerized db in the wrong way?

Comment: Can you connect to the database with `psql`, `mysql`, or a similar client tool and just run these scripts?  Why do they have to be tied to the database startup?  (Is this different from [your subsequent question](/q/77110956)?)

Comment: that's possible, maybe my main aversion is that I want this initial script to create an app-specific user and database, and I'd rather not pass the root password around to every container that needs it.

Comment: perhaps that's an old-school pre-docker way of thinking? I'm dockerizing a multi-tenant db server that hosts dbs for dozens of small sites/utilities. I was assuming that spinning up dozens of db containers for each site would be needlessly wasteful of resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that scripts placed under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ will run on the very first container star

That is not true. Docker does not run it on the first container start. A specific docker image has a specific script in `ENTRYPOINT` that will run that directory. This is not universal.

> is there an automatic version of this that will run on every container start?

No.

What you do is put your custom script inside `ENTRYPOINT` and *if* the user does not overwrite entrypoint and agrees to run yours (the default), then your script will run.